# Firebase console sdk setup showing as unfinished

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

[image]I created an android application on Android studio 3.4.2 and integrated Firebase using the firebase assistant tool provided on Android studio.There is no problem with using the features of Firebase on the app but when going to the developer's console of Firebase and going to the  project overview, it appears as if the the sdk setup  is not finished ,I tried following the sdk setup steps provided and the setup won't finish at the last stage i.e, "checking if the app has communicated with our servers,you may need to uninstall and reinstall the app". I've uninstalled my app and reinstalled it but doesn't seem to be registering the app on the Firebase server.

I've tried restarting the internet, Uninstalled my app and reinstalled,made sure net connectivity are okay on both emulator and pc

Comment: You can skip that step. Later Firebase automatically connects to the Application and shows the Analytics of Application. Just Fill proper information.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Firebase console projects, Is there any project with the same **package name**?. If there is any please **remove** and **try again**.